# Can't add Java 1.8.271 x64 to Install4j Build

Tags: install4j

I built the jre bundles for my Install4j projects with cygwin since 5 years. I always downloaded the standalone jre from oracle and created the jre bundle. It worked fine all the time. By the way, we have two build server with install4j 8.0.3 and install4j 8.0.3.

So as always i created the jre bundle with the new java 1.8.271 and we got an Error with the 8.0.3. After the line where the component.root.dir varibale is replaced we get :

Build failed.

Cause: com.exe4j.a.d
java.io.EOFException
Cause: java.io.EOFException

Stack trace:

com.exe4j.a.d: java.io.EOFException
at com.install4j.b.o.b(ejt:235)
at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:100)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:202)
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:170)
at com.install4j.jdk.v.d(ejt:135)
at com.install4j.jdk.v.b(ejt:74)
at com.install4j.b.c.a(ejt:953)
at com.install4j.b.c.g(ejt:931)
at com.install4j.b.c.a(ejt:907)
at com.install4j.b.c.W(ejt:890)
at com.install4j.b.o.a(ejt:488)
at com.install4j.b.o.b(ejt:166)
... 1 more

With the install4j 8.0.8 we don't get this error. Even if i create the jre bundle with the CreateBundle.exe we get the error with 8.0.3. Only when i create jre bundles from the jdk it works with the version 8.0.3. With cygwin und createbundle.exe.

i don't now why we get this error with the install4j 8.0.3 and the jre bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any .tar.gz bundle in this context. You have to create the bundle file via

```
Project->Create a JRE bundle
```

in the install4j IDE or use the `bin/createbundle` command line utility that comes with install4j.

Comment: I used the jre tar.gz files jre for 5 years now. i always created these jre bundles with cygwin and it worked without any problem. i'll try your way to create it.

Comment: can you plz check my new answer :)

Comment: I would not use answers in that way, they usually get deleted. Just edit your question instead and add the new content.  I'm not sure what is new now did you build it with Project.>Create a JRE bundle?

Comment: maybe you understand my problem a bit more?

Comment: Can you please check my new question?

Comment: Please try it with install4j 8.0.9 and attach the stack trace if the problem persists.